# Prove that $A' - B' \subset (A-B)'$

Tags: general-topology

To show that one set is a subset of another, we should prove that elements in the subset are also elements in the super set.

Let $x$ be an element of $A' - B'$. Then x is a limit point of A but not of B. Hence, for all $r>0$ an open ball around x intersects A. For some $\alpha > 0$, an open ball around x does not intersect B.

Where can I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x$ is a limit point of $A$ but not of $B$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $r<\epsilon$, $B_r(x)$ there is a $y\in B_r(x)$ such that  $y\ne x$, $y\in A$ and $y\notin B$.  In other words, $y\in A\setminus B$.  Hence, $x$ is a limit point of $A\setminus B$.